# List as a value in YAML

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I have a YAML template which will be filled out through user inputs. The part to focus on is "hardware" since the value can be e.g. `[abc, def]` or `abc` or `[abc, def, ghi]`.

When the input is `'abc'`. In the YAML it shows up as `abc`. But when the value is `'[abc, def]'` it shows up as `'[abc, def]'` with the quotes. I am looking to find a way to not include the *quotes*.

```py
TEMPLATE = """
router:
  arrangements:
  - range:
      start: INPUT
      stop: INPUT
    hardware: INPUT
  - range:
      start: INPUT
      stop: INPUT
    hardware: INPUT
"""

yaml = YAML()
config = yaml.load(TEMPLATE)
config['router']['arrangements'][1]['hardware'] = '[def, ghi]'

data_format = ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap(config)

with open('test.yaml', 'w') as _f:
    ruamel.yaml.dump(
        data_format,
        stream=_f,
        Dumper=ruamel.yaml.RoundTripDumper,
        explicit_start=False,
        width=1024
    )
```

Intended output:

```
hardware: [def, ghi]
```

Current output:

```
hardware: '[def, ghi]'
```

Comment: While YAML is just a *text* file, its purpose to represents an *objects*. You want YAML to represent a **string** ``'[def, ghi]'`` as a **sequence** `[def, ghi]`, and this is a **bad intention**. Instead, it is better to assign to `config['router']['arrangements'][1]['hardware']` a list (or tuple) `[def, ghi]`, and only then bother about one-line YAML representation (which would actually be a *flow-style*). Not sure why @larsks deleted his answer: that answer provided a right approach.

Comment: @Tsyvarev the input from the user would eventually show up as List ['def', 'ghi']. That just needs to be displayed as [def, ghi]. I get the point that larsks stated. It was just a matter of displaying it in the Intended fashion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the round-trip dumper, ruamel.yaml by default dumps any added dicts / lists in block style.
If you want to create a sequence in flow style you have to take the extra steps the library takes
when round-tripping flow-style elements:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

TEMPLATE = """
router:
  arrangements:
  - range:
      start: INPUT
      stop: INPUT
    hardware: INPUT
  - range:
      start: INPUT
      stop: INPUT
    hardware: INPUT
"""

def flow_seq(l):
    ret_val = ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedSeq(l)
    ret_val.fa.set_flow_style()
    return ret_val

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.explicit_start = False
yaml.width = 1024

config = yaml.load(TEMPLATE)
config['router']['arrangements'][1]['hardware'] = flow_seq(['def', 'ghi'])

assert isinstance(config, ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap)

yaml.dump(config, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
router:
  arrangements:
  - range:
      start: INPUT
      stop: INPUT
    hardware: INPUT
  - range:
      start: INPUT
      stop: INPUT
    hardware: [def, ghi]
```

There is no need to use the old style `ruamel.yaml.dump()` for output as you did. You can control the `YAML()` instance
you used for input for output by setting its attributes.

I also recommend testing by streaming to stdout, much easier than looking at the contents of a file.
Once things work you can replace the last line with:

```
 from pathlib import Path
 out_file = Path('test.yaml')

 yaml.dump(config, out_file)
```

If the user input comes as the bracket delimited string `'[def, ghi]'`, you can convert that using something like

```
s = '[def, ghi]'  # replace by the user input
l = [x.strip() for x in s.lstrip('[').rstrip(']').split(',')]
```

Comment: That worked out perfectly! Thank you so much. Also, thank you for the bonus tip on the user input.